# Extract vector from a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R , and I would like to extract two different vectors from third column of this data frame such that when the element of first column is equal to the second column , then extract the third column values in a vector `d` and otherwise in a vector `e`. how can I do this?

```
     > df = data.frame("a"=c(1, 2, 4, 7), b = c(Inf, 2, Inf, 7), c=c(1, 0, 0, 1))
     > df
       a   b c
     1 1 Inf 1
     2 2   2 0
     3 4 Inf 0
     4 7   7 1

     > d = c(0, 1)
     > e = c(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
d <- df[df$a==df$b,3]  
e <- df[df$a!=df$b,3]  
> d  
[1] 0 1    
> e  
[1] 1 0
```